# R model.matrix column names for factors

Tags: r, names, model.matrix

I use model.matrix to create a matrix used by GLM.

```
formula_test <- as.formula("Y ~ x1 + x2")
data_test <- expand.grid(
  Y = 1:100
  , x1 = c("A","B")
  , x2 = 1:20
)
result_test <- data.frame(model.matrix(
  object = formula_test
  , data = data_test
))
names(result_test)
```

Interestingly, the column names of the result_test data are `"X.Intercept." "x1B" "x2"`

How come the second column name is not `"x1A"`?

I then tried `data_test$x1 <- factor(x = data_test$x1, levels = c("A","B"))`but it's still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because if you had `c("X.Intercept.", "x1A", "x1B", "x2")`, then you would have perfect multicollinearity: `x1A + x1B` would be a column of ones, just like the `X.Intercept.` column. If, for the sake of interpretation, you prefer having `x1A` instead of the intercept, we may use

```
formula_test <- as.formula("Y ~ -1 + x1 + x2")
```

giving

```
names(result_test)
# [1] "x1A" "x1B" "x2"
```

and

```
all(rowSums(result_test[, c("x1A", "x1B")]) == 1)
# [1] TRUE
```

As for why it is `x1A` that is dropped rather than `x1B`, the rule seems to be that the first factor levels goes away. If instead we use

```
levels(data_test$x1) <- c("B", "A")
```

then this gives

```
names(result_test)
# [1] "X.Intercept." "x1A"          "x2"
```

Comment: Thanks. what I meant in the question is, I expected the column names to be `"X.Intercept." "x1A" "x2"` than `"X.Intercept." "x1B" "x2"` because the value 'A' comes first than 'B' (for column x1).

Comment: @LeGeniusII, I see. See the update, perhaps that helps.